# > Could not find com.facebook.react:react-native:0.73.2

Tags: react-native, expo, dependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.facebook.react:react-native:0.73.2.
> Required by:
> project :app
> project :app > project :react-native-firebase_app
> project :app > project :react-native-firebase_remote-config
> project :app > project :stripe_stripe-react-native
> project :app > project :react-native-pager-view

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 36s

node 21
java 17
gradle 8.3
rn 0.73.2
expo 50